# How to decide halloween costume for babies?

Tags: halloween

I have twin girls. Both the babies are 12 months old, and my husband has bought halloween costume for them as I just didnt have any idea what they may want to become.
So my basic question is,  if the babies are too young to talk and tell their preference, then on what basis should we buy a costume for them?

Wanted to add, my babies are going to be pumpkin and snow white :)

Comment: Pumpkin and Snow White?! Not Cinderella?! The heresy!

Comment: Haha..:) snow white costume was available and affordable :)

Comment: Most babies prefer to be either a pumpkin or Yoda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At that age it is pretty much irrelevant what your baby may want to become. It is not a concept they will know or have. They have no idea what a witch is, or a mummy, or a zombie.

The important thing is for you, your family and friends to have fun, and perhaps have something you can look back on in future and see that the babies looked cute/funny/whatever in photographs.

To be honest, if you buy a baby Halloween costume, it will be cute - shops have no mileage in trying to make babies look horrible. As they get older that may change (my 12 year old looked an absolutely hideous zombie at her school Halloween party the other night, but that was her choice)

What you will want to do is make sure they cope with all the scary folks they will meet at a party or trick or treating :-)

Answer (score 12):

At that age, I think costumes are *entirely* for the parents to enjoy :) The kids (and someday their children) can't enjoy until a much older age when they see photographs of how adorable they looked. Cute pumpkin and princess costumes sound perfect.

The only thing I'd note is that you should *consider safety issues*: avoid excessive ribbons, sparkles, buttons, or any decoration that could be pulled off and eaten. Most costumes sold for kids under three won't have such things anyway, though!